# Can I make the system to check checksums of all the binary files installed?

Tags: apt

I've found a bad bit in my RAM and still experience some notable bugs after replacing it. I suspect some binaries could get corrupted during installation. Can the system check the installed binaries checksums based on the packages metadata?

Answer (score 6):

The MD5 sums of files installed by .deb packages are stored in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/*.md5sums`. Run the following to check the integrity of all files:

```
cd /
md5sum -c /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.md5sums
```

Or, to see only the failures:

```
cd /
LC_ALL=C md5sum --quiet -c /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.md5sums
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `debsums -s` to check the MD5 sums of installed Debian packages.